# can't use variables in jquery function

Tags: jquery, variables, toggle

I have a very simple jquery script that basically toggles two elements between two classes. Not entirely relevant, but the goal is to have an off canvas slide into place. Everything works, but I can't get the off-canvas panel to toggle because apparently I'm not using variable names correctly. I tried all options and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".toggleFilter").click(function() {
    var filterPanel = $(this).attr("href").replace("#", "");
    console.log(filterPanel);
    var filterPanelOpen = filterPanel + "Open";
    console.log(filterPanelOpen);
    $(".container, .containerLeft").toggleClass("container containerLeft");
    $("." + filterPanel, "." + filterPanelOpen).toggleClass(filterPanel filterPanelOpen);
  });
});
```

The line that toggles the container works absolutely fine and the variables are logged in the console, so I know they're correct. For some reason, the last line doesn't do what I want. Why isn't that line equal to?

```
$("filterPanel, filterPanelOpen").toggleClass("filterPanel filterPanelOpen");
```

It seems that since I use variables, I need to use a different syntax, but I can't figure out what jquery expects. All other topics say that using the variable name only is enough, but that clearly doesn't work.

Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: Functions take parameter values as input. `filterPanel filterPanelOpen` isn't one parameter, but two parameters, and the space between them makes it an illegal expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are not appending the variables to one another, this should produce a `SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`, you can add the variables and a space between them like so:

```
.toggleClass(filterPanel + " " + filterPanelOpen);
```

Adding a space between them.

Additionally, you are calling `$()` with two parameters, by not including the comma between them in one of the String expressions:

```
$("." + filterPanel + ", ." + filterPanelOpen)
```

Change the two and the function should work:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".toggleFilter").click(function() {
    var filterPanel = $(this).attr("href").replace("#", "");
    console.log(filterPanel);
    var filterPanelOpen = filterPanel + "Open";
    console.log(filterPanelOpen);
    $(".container, .containerLeft").toggleClass("container containerLeft");
    $("." + filterPanel+ ", ." + filterPanelOpen).toggleClass(filterPanel + " " + filterPanelOpen);
  });
});
```

---

If you can use a template literal in your environment (you're targeting only modern browsers, or using transpiling), it might be clearer if you use one (at least for the selector, and possibly also for the class list in `toggleClass`):

```
$(`.${filterPanel}, .${filterPanelOpen}`).toggleClass(`${filterPanel} ${filterPanelOpen}`);
```

Comment: thanks, this did the trick indeed. these things are so easy, but I can't seem to wrap my head around js. must be a psychological thing. thanks again!

Comment: You'll get it eventually ;-)